# WordPress how to add TinyMCE format row function to Post->ID Excerpt filter

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I am using the forced excerpt code to automatically generate excerpt content without using the more tag or the excerpt editor box as follows in functions.php:

```
function mytheme_excerpt_read_more_link( $output ) {
  global $post;
  return $output . ' <div class="more-link">
  <a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '>Read More</a></div>';
  }
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'mytheme_excerpt_read_more_link' );
```

However, I need to add the TinyMCE function so that if someone adds italic (for example) in the editor the `<em>` will be picked up in the excerpt code.

This is what I have to customize the TinyMCE:

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'mrw_mce_buttons_1' );
  function mrw_mce_buttons_1( $buttons ) {
  $buttons = array('styleselect', 'bold', 'italic', 
  'link', 'unlink', 'bullist', 'numlist', 'indent', 
  'outdent', 'pastetext', 'removeformat', 'charmap', 
  'undo', 'redo',  'wp_more','wp_help',  );

return $buttons;
}
```

How do I add the above filter to the Post->ID?  I tried this but it didn't work:

```
 function my_theme_add_tinymce_styles() {
    global $post;
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    $tinymce_style = 'mrw_mce_buttons_1';
    add_editor_style( $tinymce_style );
    }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_theme_add_tinymce_styles' );
```

Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 0):

This puts the same tinyMCE setup that's in the Editor window into the Excerpt window:

```
<?php
//adjust Excerpt box height
function admin_excerpt() { echo "<style>"; echo "textarea#excerpt {height:300px;}"; echo "</style>"; } add_action('admin_head', 'admin_excerpt');


/*from http://easywebdesigntutorials.com/customizing-the-excerpts-meta-box/
Code to adding the TinyMCE visual editor to an excerpt is from:
https://marcgratch.com/add-tinymce-to-excerpt/

Code 1.
To me this seems like the best code of the 3 to use. */


function lb_editor_remove_meta_box() {
 global $post_type;
/**
 * Check to see if the global $post_type variable exists
 * and then check to see if the current post_type supports
 * excerpts. If so, remove the default excerpt meta box
 * provided by the WordPress core. If you would like to only
 * change the excerpt meta box for certain post types replace
 * $post_type with the post_type identifier.
 */
 if (isset($post_type) && post_type_supports($post_type, 'excerpt')){
 remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', $post_type, 'normal');
 } 
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'lb_editor_remove_meta_box');

function lb_editor_add_custom_meta_box() {
 global $post_type;
 /**
 * Again, check to see if the global $post_type variable
 * exists and then if the current post_type supports excerpts.
 * If so, add the new custom excerpt meta box. If you would
 * like to only change the excerpt meta box for certain post
 * types replace $post_type with the post_type identifier.
 */
 if (isset($post_type) && post_type_supports($post_type, 'excerpt')){
 add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'lb_editor_custom_post_excerpt_meta_box', $post_type, 'normal', 'high');
 }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'lb_editor_add_custom_meta_box' );

function lb_editor_custom_post_excerpt_meta_box( $post ) {

/**
 * Adjust the settings for the new wp_editor. For all
 * available settings view the wp_editor reference
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor
 */
 $settings = array( 'textarea_rows' => '12', 'quicktags' => true, 'tinymce' => true);

/**
 * Create the new meta box editor and decode the current
 * post_excerpt value so the TinyMCE editor can display
 * the content as it is styled.
 */
 wp_editor(html_entity_decode(stripcslashes($post->post_excerpt)), 'excerpt', $settings);

 // The meta box description - adjust as necessary
// echo '&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Excerpts are optional, hand-crafted, summaries of your content.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
}

// add Text (HTML)
```